# "Send Email" Activity in Lead detail page for Partner Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, email, activities, partner-communities

How can I add Send Email activity in Leads's record page for partner community portal. Post and Poll options are available but am not able to get email action in lead record page. Please somebody help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your Global layouts include the standard Send Email Action.